# why *ngIf validation message always appear?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using angular and HTML. I make pattern validation to first name that should not accept only numbers.

```
    <fieldset class="six">
     <input id="firstName" ng-pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" type="text" 
        [(ngModel)]="user.firstName" formControlName="firstName" 
         required autocomplete="given-name" placeholder="First 
                  name"/>
            <label class="validation-message alert" 
           *ngIf="( (!newUserForm.controls.firstName 
              ||user.firstName.trim().length == 0 ) && 
                (newUserForm.controls.firstName.touched))">
                     First Name is required </label>
            <label class="validation-message alert" *ngif=" 
              newUserForm.firstName.touched " ng-message=" 
              newUserForm.firstName.hasError('firstName')">
               Invalid First Name </label>
     </fieldset>
```

My problem is that the invalid first name always appears. Can any one help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your ngIf says to show the message if firstName is touched. It says nothing about it being valid or not.

Comment: *ngIf=" newUserForm.firstName.touched && newUserForm.firstName.hasError('firstName').ng-pattern " this is my condition , is it correct ?

Comment: if newUserForm is a formGroup, you need to do newUserForm.get('firstName').... Additionally, hasError returns a boolean, not an object.... So, you should try something like this.... newUserForm.get('firstName').touched && newUserForm.get('firstName').hasError('pattern')